# What is wrong with this csv to mysql upload?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, file-upload, upload

I built this script to upload .csv files and directly send them to my database.
But it doesn't write anything into my table.
If i uploade the file to my server and write "file.csv" instead of "$file" it works perfectly..
But I want to upload them via form.
Can anyone help me?

Form:

```
<html> 
<head> 
</head> 
<body> 

<h2> CSV Import </h2> 
<form>
 <form method="post" action="imp.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  <input type="file" name="file" /> 
  <br /> 
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

imp.php:

```
<?php
$delimiter = ',';

$db = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pw', 'db');


$file= $_FILES[file][temp_name];


if (($handle = fopen($file, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
        foreach($data as $i => $content) {
            $data[$i] = $db->real_escape_string($content);
        }
        $db->query("INSERT INTO table VALUES('" . implode("','", $data) . "');");
    }
    fclose($handle);
}


?>
```

Comment: can you var_dump($_FILES)?

Comment: let's see... failure to verify that the upload suceeded. failure to verify that the db connection was established. failure to verify that the query calls suceeded. using `'` to echo variable-containing strings... shall we continue?

Comment: upload suceeded! db connection is ok! I just made an edit.. echo '$file'; is not part of the program

Comment: Failure to quote strings `$_FILES['file']['temp_name']`

Comment: doesn't change anything.. :/

Comment: Add `or die($db->error)` to the end of the `$db->query` line, to report errors.

Comment: I know it doesn't change anything, it's just poor coding. If you had warnings enabled, you would be getting notices about it.

Comment: warnings are enabled..
no errors occur..

Comment: why is it working when I just type in the file's name but not with this upload form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

ie not `temp_name`

Comment: This Error occurs:
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
But i tried to upload the same without the form and it worked..
don't get it..
how can that be possible?

Comment: Well you must be uploading a file with a different number of columns!

Comment: no..
I first exported the mysql as CSV and then tried to import it...
It should be the same number of collums or?? :)

Comment: Maybe your CSV wasnt created entirely correct? Did you definitly get all the escaping right? Also maybe not all rows have the right number of columns? (ie not enough commas)

Comment: phpMyAdmin exported it as CSV..
 do you think i can trust this?

Comment: Depends a large part on what options you set when exporting... If you used the Excel option might be ok, but the CSV for example defaults to ; as the seperator.

Comment: Okay I got it now...
$delimiter should be ;
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest using `LOAD DATA INFILE` syntax since you have a well-structured CSV on your server to being with.

Something like:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/local/file'
INTO TABLE table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

This will allow you to upload all content with a single query.  Also note that if your MySQL server and application server are on the same machine, you would be able to omit the `LOCAL` option as MySQL could reads the file directly from the file system at the path specified (assuming it has permissions).

This eliminates the need to open the file and iterate through it.

If you do not want to go this routes, I would at least suggest doing bulk inserts and adding multiple rows at a time (rather than having a single insert query for each row).